# ubuntu libraries not found error when building

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, build, shared-libraries

I have prepared a setup.py file which requires the opencv libraries contrib,core and highgui. But when I build the setup.py I get an error saying

```
/usr/bin/ld:cannot find -lcontrib 
/usr/bin/ld:cannot find -lcore
/usr/bin/ld:cannot find -lhighgui
```

I added an entry, "include /usr/local/lib" to the ld.so.conf file and ran the command ldconfig from the terminal. Still getting the same error. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The linker flags should be `-lopencv_contrib`, `-lopencv_core` and `-lopencv_highgui` for a standard OpenCV2.4+ install from source or when using pre-built binaries. Also make sure these libraries do exist in `/usr/local/lib`. You could run `ls /usr/local/lib | grep opencv` to see if they exist.

Comment: I ran the "ls /usr/local/lib | grep opencv" command and they are there with names -libopencv_contrib,libopencv_core and libopencv_highgui. How can I change these? pls advice

Comment: Okay. Then you do have the OpenCV library installed properly. The linker flags should be `-lopencv_contrib` instead of `-lcontrib` similarly `-opencv_core` and `-lopencv_highgui`.
 Can you post the relevant lines in your setup.py file?